# I'm having a problem with kivy, python 3.7.6, it doesn't generate a window despite of having all the packages installed

Tags: python, kivy

Please check for any error and help me. I've tried many different things but nothing seems to help.

**Only this shows up after running the code, but no window**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Ola mundo')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

The resulting log:

```
"C:\Users\anjo pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" "C:/Users/anjo 
pedro/PycharmProjects/testando/fllightPlan.py"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\anjo pedro\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-05-01_6.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle_dev" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2_dev" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\anjo 
pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit 
(AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\anjo 
pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer 
ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2

Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the shortest possible code that unexpectedly produces this behavior when run without changes. Right now, only you have your `flightPlan.py`, so we have no way to see the problem ourselves or test whether a proposed fix works.

Comment: (It might be helpful to start with one of the examples Kivy comes with, and determine the smallest necessary change to make that generate cause the same error; by contrast, if a stock out-of-the-box example causes the same problem, that's an important detail to include in the question).

Comment: I add the code I´m running, i think it´s pretty normal...

Comment: Is there a `my.kv` file in the same folder as your python code?

Comment: no, just that code.

Comment: I found a solution, now it is working properly. I just updated my OpenGL and create a path (variable: KIVY_GL_BACKEND  value: agle_sdl2) at envoirement variable, users variable.